# Trigger tintColorDidChange to desaturate tinted elements in response to user action

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, tintcolor

You can override `tintColorDidChange` in a `UIView` subclass and access the `tintAdjustmentMode` in order to know when iOS is going to desaturate your elements when an alert is shown for example.

I am implementing a custom modal control that should cause iOS to desaturate the underlying views. How can I trigger that, is there a notification I can post?

I can manually set the tint color to `UIColor(white: 128/255, alpha: 1)` in order to fake this, then reset it when appropriate, but this is a poor workaround as it's not truly desaturating the elements, instead just applying a different tint color.

Comment: Could you set the window's tintAdjustmentMode to UIViewTintAdjustmentModeDimmed and then set the alert's tintAdjustmentMode to UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal?

Comment: @TheSD Hey that worked beautifully. Care to answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the window's `tintAdjustmentMode` to `UIViewTintAdjustmentModeDimmed` and then set the alert's `tintAdjustmentMode` to `UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal`.